# Impact of Jordan/Egypt travel on US/EU/Canada visa application

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, b1-b2-visas, middle-east

I am an Indian resident and citizen with no international travel history.
I am working in a US tech company with a steady income.
Being history buffs, a couple of my colleagues and I are planning a trip to Jordan or Egypt or Both.
This would imply that post the trip my entire travel history would be to the middle east.

I have heard rumors stating that such travel history can negatively impact visa applications to 'the west' namely US/Canada/EU. Is there any weight to this?
Would previous visit to Jordan / Egypt lead to tourist visa rejections? (assuming that other supporting documentation is in place and rejection is solely on visit to other country).

Comment: No, just rumors!